# Gradle project dependency does not build dependency project

Tags: gradle, gradlefx

I have a Gradle multi project.

One of projects is Flex project, which is built using gradleFx plugin.

The second is war project and I need include the SWF file from Flex project into the war.

I add

```
war { 
  from (project(":flex:FlexManager").buildDir) {into ('flash')}
}
```

and it does put the SWF into war, but only if the SWF already exists.

Then I want that gradle will build the :flex:FlexManager project during the build of my war. So I add

```
dependencies {
  ....
  runtime project(path : ':flex:FlexManager')
}
```

The only way I found to start the flex project build during war build was

```
war { 
  ...
   dependsOn ':flex:FlexManager:build'
}
```

but it looks like not the best way - I prefer define project dependencies instead of tasks dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you need to change is to specify that you want to copy from a task or task outputs and not a directory - this will register an implicit dependency between your war task and whatever task that builds the swf file.

Said that it is necessary for the task that builds your swf file to specify its outputs. I had a quick look at GradleFx and unfortunately it looks like compileFlex task doesn't do it. So first you will need to specify the outputs for the task the following way:

```
compileFlex {
    outputs.dir project.buildDir
}
```

and then modify your war task configuration:

```
war {
    from project(":flex:FlexManager").compileFlex {
        into ('flash')
    }
}
```

You should probably also nag at the GradleFx devs to add outputs to their tasks. :)

**EDIT:**

From the discussion in the comments I've understood that instead of depending on a task you can depend on a project artifact. The cleanest way is to create a custom configuration, add the dependency to it and then use it in the from call when configuring the war task:

```
configuration {
    flex
}

dependencies {
    flex project(':flex:FlexManager')
}

war {
    from configurations.flex {
        into ('flash')
    }
}
```

You could probably also use the archives or default configuration of `:flex:FlexManager` directly:

```
war {
    from project(':flex:FlexManager').configurations.archives {
        into ('flash')
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps, thank you! 
But can I create a dependency between projects, not tasks?

Comment: No you cannot, there is no such concept in Gradle, you can only specify a dependency between tasks. What would you need a project dependency for?

Comment: Thank you, I do not need. I just thought that just as for external dependency we define dependency on the artifact (i.e. result of build), in the same way I can define it for project dependency - i.e. my project depends on  another project artifact (build result)

Comment: Oh, now I know what you mean. You are referring to trying to add a runtime dependency on project(':flex:FlexManager') as in your question. This is completely valid as described here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:project_dependencies. The problem is that you used the runtime configuration which is not resolved when running war task. You would need to create a custom configuration and add the project dependency to it and then in your war task use the configuration in the from call as a configuration is a FileCollection and can be used that way

Comment: I tried also to do it with 'compile' configuration, which is supported by war plugin, but again - w/o success

Comment: I had another look at the source code of GradleFx and it [does define artifacts](https://github.com/GradleFx/GradleFx/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradlefx/plugins/GradleFxPlugin.groovy#L85) for both default and archives configurations but it does not define which task the artifacts are built by. This means that the implicit dependency between projects cannot be determined, as it doesn't know which task has to be executed for the artifact to be built. This is another thing that could porbably be improved in GradleFx...

Comment: @erdi Just wanted to note that all compile tasks in GradleFx [do specify an output](https://github.com/GradleFx/GradleFx/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradlefx/tasks/compile/Compile.groovy#L64). As for your remark on the artifacts: we'll surely look into this.

Comment: @RIAstar Yes, it looks like the compile tasks do specify an output. I only looked for Output annotations on the task fields and when I couldn't see any I assumed that the outputs are not defined as using the annotation is the more popular way of defining outputs on custom task classes.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar requirement in my project. I need to include swf file which is an output of flex project into java project and build the war.

```
1. I created a two sub project under war project, flex and java.
2. Included them in settings file.
3. The main build.gradle file has basic configuration.
4. In flex sub project gradlefx plugin is applied and the output swf file is copied to the directory using a copy task.
5. In java sub project war plugin is applied and the source directory is mentioned from which war has to be generated.
```

Here is an example code for your reference:

settings.xml:

```
include myproject,
myproject:mysubproject:flex,
myproject:mysubproject:java
```

build.gradle file in myproject dir:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath project (":FlexProject") //include all the flex project from which the swf file to be included
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath project (":JavaProject") //include all the dependent java project if any
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    output.classesDir   = 'root/WEB-INF/classes' //This is the directory from which I am going to generate war.
  }
}
```

build.gradle file in myproject/mysubproject/flex dir:

```
apply plugin: 'gradlefx'
type = 'swf'
dependencies{
    merged project (":FlexProject")
}

String rootProjectDir = rootDir
rootProjectDir = rootProjectDir.replaceAll("\\\\","/")

task copyTask <<{
    copy{
        from rootProjectDir +'/MyFlexProject1/build'
        into rootProjectDir +'/myproject/root'
        include '**/*.swf'
    }
}
build.finalizedBy(copyTask)
```

build.gradle file in myproject/mysubproject/java dir:

```
String rootProjectDir = rootDir
rootProjectDir = rootProjectDir.replaceAll("\\\\","/")
String rootProjectDirDocRoot = rootProjectDir + '/myproject/root'

dependencies {
    compile project (":JavaProject")    //to include dependent jars in war
}

group = "com.abc.enterprise"
archivesBaseName = "myprojet"
description = "myproject"
apply plugin: 'war'

war{
    from rootProjectDirDocRoot
    exclude('.gradle')
    exclude('.settings')
}
```

This will compile the flex project every time and he swf file will in be included into the directory from which the war has to be built. Hope this helps.